# Context Module - not triggering menu active

Tags: 7

I need the menu called "Questionários" to be active/visible (and styled in different color) only for the node 115.

I've installed the **context module** and tried to use the path pointing to my node but it didn't work.

Here's a print (some things are in Portuguese but I hope you can understand):
[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Have you checked the issue queue for Context module?

Comment: No, I didn't think this was a bug or something malfunctioning, I thought I was doing something wrong. But I'll look at the issue queue. Thanks.

Comment: My version is 7.x-3.6 and there are no reports for that issue...

Answer (score 0):

The patch is here: https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/context-fix-menu-reaction-2374445-16.patch

It will fix the issue for the main menu set as a block.